# Hiding DGV Rows onload/TabPage Selection

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

Wondering why I can't successfully run this code onload or when tabpage selected -(will run on button click)

```
For Each Row In DataGridView1.Rows

            If Not Row.index = 0 And Row.index < DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1 Then

                If Not Row.Cells(6).Value = WhoIsIt Then
                    Row.Visible = False
                Else
                    Row.Visible = True
                End If

            Else

                If Not Row.Cells(6).Value = WhoIsIt And Row.index < DataGridView1.Rows.Count Then
                    Row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Black
                End If

            End If

        Next
```

Background: The DGV is connected to an access table. My goal is to have it only show rows that have the Users initials in the cell being checked.

Answer (score 0):

simply use this code

```
for i as integer =0 to DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1   
       if DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(6).Value <> WhoIsIt then  
          DataGridView1.Rows(i).visible=false  
       end if  
next
```